# Termination of prolog query using using dcgs

Tags: prolog, dcg, non-termination

Given the program

```
foo([]) --> [].
foo([Start|Rest]) --> alphanum(Start), foo(Rest).

alphanum(Ch)  --> [Ch], { char_type(Ch, alnum) }.
```

How can I make the query `length(I, 2), phrase(foo(C), I), false.` terminate?
I am using `SWI-Prolog version 8.4.3 for x86_64-linux`

The non-termination seems to be originating from the last dcg rule. With the following program **(not what I want)**, the query terminates.

```
foo([]) --> [].
foo([Start|Rest]) --> alphanum(Start), foo(Rest).

alphanum(Ch)  --> [Ch].
```

I don't mind any other formulation of the program that achieves the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *will* terminate - but there's a lot of Unicode character combinations to loop through.

You probably want instead (note that this is using usually-preferable [codes](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) instead of chars):

```
foo([]) --> [].
foo([Start|Rest]) --> alnum(Start), foo(Rest).

alnum(Digit) --> [Digit], { between(0'0, 0'9, Digit) }.
alnum(Lower) --> [Lower], { between(0'a, 0'z, Lower) }.
alnum(Upper) --> [Upper], { between(0'A, 0'Z, Upper) }.
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- length(I, 2), phrase(foo(C), I), writeln(I), false.
...
[90,88]
[90,89]
[90,90]
false.
```